# Copying variable value form shell script to constant file

Tags: shell-script, sed

I have `appcenter-pre-build.sh` in which I am executing another script depend on environment type. If environment is UAT then it will execute `uat-pre-build.sh`.

Here is `appcenter-pre-build.sh`

```
if [ -z "$ENV_TYPE" ]
then
    echo "You need define the ENV_TYPE variable in App Center"
    exit
fi
echo "ENV_TYPE is : - $ENV_TYPE"    
if [ "UAT" = "$ENV_TYPE" ]
then
    echo "Environment type : UAT"
    ENV_FILE=$APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/ABC/config/uat-pre-build.sh
else
    echo "you need to mentioned correct envrionment type"
    exit
fi
echo "Environment file : $ENV_FILE"
sh "$ENV_FILE"
```

I have three different script depends on build environment.

1. uat-pre-build.sh
2. dev-pre-build.sh
3. prod-pre-build.sh

In above script I am reading variable value and trying to assigning it into ConfigurationHelper.cs.

Here is my uat-pre-build.sh

```
APP_ID=b1a4a39f-4d89-4f04-98d8-2a20eda89aad
# Get ConfigurationHelper.cs from project
APP_CONSTANT_FILE=$APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/helpers/ConfigurationHelper.cs

if [ -e "$APP_CONSTANT_FILE" ]
then
    echo "Updating environment configs in AppConstant.cs"

    sed -i '' 's#ApplicationID = "[-A-Za-z0-9:_./]*"#ApplicationID = "'$APP_ID'"#' $APP_CONSTANT_FILE

    echo "File content:"
    cat $APP_CONSTANT_FILE
else
        echo "Can not locate $APP_CONSTANT_FILE file"
fi
```

Here is ConfigurationHelper.cs

```
public class ConfigurationHelper
{
    public static string ApplicationID = string.Empty;
    static ConfigurationHelper(){}

}
```

I am able to execute script but unable to assign APP_ID value from `uat-pre-build.sh` to ApplicationID in `ConfigurationHelper.cs`. Seems following line is not executing correctly.

```
sed -i '' 's#ApplicationID = "[-A-Za-z0-9:_./]*"#ApplicationID = "'$APP_ID'"#' $APP_CONSTANT_FILE
```

Here is output from app center.

```
[command]/bin/bash 

/Users/vsts/agent/2.153.1/work/1/s/ABC.Android/appcenter-pre-build.sh
ENV_TYPE is : - UAT
Environment type : UAT
Environment file : /Users/vsts/agent/2.153.1/work/1/s/ABC/config/uat-pre-build.sh
Updating environment configs in AppConstant.cs
File content:
﻿
namespace ABC.Business.Helpers
{
/// <summary>
/// The configuration helper.
/// </summary>
public class ConfigurationHelper
{
    public static string ApplicationID = string.Empty;


    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes static members of the <see cref="ConfigurationHelper"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    static ConfigurationHelper()
    {
    }

    }

}
```

Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to want to substitute the `string.Empty` in your `ConfigurationHelper.cs` file but as you've discovered, the substitution you're using will never match. You've got `ApplicationID = "[-A-Za-z0-9:_./]*"`. This could match

```
public static string ApplicationID = "string.Empty";
```

but since you've explicitly specified the double quote characters in the match pattern they have to be present in the source.

You could try a straight match, `ApplicationID = string.Empty`. If you really need the complexity of either `string.Empty` or a quoted string, what about `ApplicationID = \(string.Empty|".*"\)`

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't need to work on weekend now. :-)